# How do I set duration of a video in ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, native-android

I need to set duration of a video for a thumbnail to 5 seconds and loop it. I got the loop part, but I can't find documentation for setting specific duration

I tried exoPlayer.seek(duration) but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`ClippingMediaSource`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ClippingMediaSource.html):

```java
ClippingMediaSource​(MediaSource mediaSource, long startPositionUs, long endPositionUs)
```

> Creates a new clipping source that wraps the specified source and provides samples between the specified start and end position.

You can convert to have a new media source and set this new media source for your ExoPlayer:

```kotlin
// Create a new media source with your specified period
val newMediaSource = ClippingMediaSource(mediaSource, 0, 5_000_000)
```